# Добавление данных в БД через кнопку

Tags: php

Как сделать чтобы введенные данные в поля `input` при нажатии на кнопку `Add` добавились в таблицу?

```
<?php
require "app_config.php"; 
header ('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_connect($database_host, $username, $password, $database_name)
or die("<p>Ошибка подключения к базе данных: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
echo "<p>Вы подключились к MySQL!</p>";
mysql_select_db($database_name)
or die("<p>Ошибка при выборе базы данных {$database_name}: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
echo "<p>Вы подключены к MySQL с использованием базы данных {$database_name}.</p>";
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES;");
if (!$result)
{
die("<p>Ошибка при выводе перечня таблиц: " . mysql_error() ."</p>");
}
echo "<p>Таблицы, имеющиеся в базе данных:</p>";
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
echo "<li>Таблица: {$row[0]}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>


<?php
require "connect.php";
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM Ships";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
echo '<table border=0>';
echo '<tr><td>Ship</td><td>Name</td><td>Captain</td><td>Type</td><td>Cargo</td><td>Build</td><td>Photo</td></tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
echo '<tr><td>'.$row['ship_id'].'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['captain_name'].'</td><td>'.$row['ship_type'].'</td><td>'.$row['cargo'].'</td><td>'.$row['build_year'].'</td><td>'.$row['photo'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>



<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset-utf-8');
require "app_config.php";
require "index0.php";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$captain_name = $_POST['captain_name'];
$ship_type = $_POST['ship_type'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$build_year = $_POST['build_year'];
$photo = $_POST['photo'];

$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO Ships (ship_id, name, captain_name, ship_type, cargo, build_year, photo) VALUES ('$ship_id', '$name', '$captain_name', '$ship_type', '$cargo', '$build_year', '$photo')";
$res=mysql_query($insert_sql);
if ($res) {
        echo "<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }


echo
'<form name="q" action="add_data.php" method="post">
<br> <hr> <br>
Name: <input name="name" type="text"> <br><br>
Captain name: <input name="captain_name" type="text"> <br><br>
Ship type: <br><br>
<input name="ship_type" type="radio" value="GP"> GP <br>
<input name="ship_type" type="radio" value="MR"> MR <br>
<input name="ship_type" type="radio" value="LR1"> LR1 <br>
<input name="ship_type" type="radio" value="LR2"> LR2 <br>
<input name="ship_type" type="radio" value="VLCC"> VLCC <br><br>
Cargo: <input name="cargo" type="number" min="16500" max="160000"> <br><br>
Build year: <input name="build_year" type="date"> <br><br>
Photo: <input name="photo" type="file"> <br><br>
<input name="add" type="submit" value="Add"> <br><br>
</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы выполнять запрос в базу данных, вы сперва должны к ней подключиться с помощью mysql_connect. Да и функции mysql_ помечены как устаревшие, пользуйтесь mysqli_ функциями. [Здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) вы можете посмотреть пример использования

Comment: Так подключение есть - require "index0.php";

Comment: @Kaya Ну из предоставленного вами кода этого не видно. Непонятно что у вас может быть в файле index0.php

Comment: @Kaya Тогда вопрос - что именно не работает? Логика работы такая и должна быть

Comment: index0.php - теперь есть в вопросе. Я хочу узнать как добавить данные в БД.

Comment: @Kaya И опять же, подключения к базе тут тоже нету. Рискну предположить что оно в connect.php А по поводу занесения в базу - у вас же есть mysql_query с запросом внесения в бд. Так и записывать в базу

Comment: Теперь подключение есть. Тот метод что у меня просто при обновлении страницы заносит пустые значения в базу. Мне жу нужно чтобы в базу вносились те значения которые я введу в поля и нажму Add

Comment: Вот мы наконец то и добрались до сути вашего впороса. Это и нужно было сразу писать. Проблема у вас в том, что код выполняется каждый раз при открытии страницы. Ну дак и добавьте условие `if (isset($_POST['add'])){ здесь код занесения в базу }` Ну а код занесения в базу у вас это все что после require и до echo

Comment: @Kaya и еще - судя по вашему коду, вы сперва подключаете app_config, затем index0, который подключает connect, а тот в свое время тоже подключает app_config т.е. app_config подключается дважды. Так делать нельзя, например если вы добавите в него объявление функции - то у вас ошибка выскочит. Либо использовать require_once, либо убрать одно из подключений

Comment: Все как нужно. Спасибо. Только есть одна проблема. Я ввожу данные и нажимаю Add и обновляю страницу чтобы проверить есть ли данные. Они есть, но почему данные опять вносятся если еще раз перезагрузить страницу? Получается если перезапускать страницу то вводятся данные, хотя поля ты пустые.